# error after in source.list.d

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after i write this comade and try to run

sudo apt-get update

ihave this error

E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/os-latest.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198156/error-after-in-source.list.d/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you didn't copy and paste the sources setup line from the install tutorial correctly.

You should probably remove /etc/apt/sources.list.d/os-latest.list and try again.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-24**:
thanks how ican remove

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-24**:
Try `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/os-latest.list`

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-11-24**:
thanks its start work